# Datastax Enterprise: shark/spark not working on new analytics node

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

### Background

I just added an Analytics node to my multi-datacenter cluster. I'm running DSE 4.5.1. Here's my topology:

```
$ dsetool ring liminex_ent
Address          DC           Rack         Workload         Status  State    Load             Effective-Ownership  VNodes                                      
172.31.22.79     Solr         rack1        Search           Up      Normal   1.31 GB          75.00%               1                                           
172.31.42.106    Solr         rack1        Search           Up      Normal   1.11 GB          58.33%               1                                           
172.31.11.202    Solr         rack1        Search           Up      Normal   1.16 GB          66.67%               1                                           
172.31.45.40     Analytics    2a           Unknown          Up      Normal   391.15 MB        100.00%              1                                           
172.31.41.76     us-west-2    2a           Unknown          Up      Normal   2.05 GB          100.00%              255                                         
172.31.50.106    us-west-2    2b           Unknown          Up      Normal   1.29 GB          0.36%                255 
172.31.8.174     us-west-2    2c           Unknown          Up      Normal   2.23 GB          99.64%               255
```

My liminex_ent keyspace has the following replication:

```
'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
'us-west-2': '2',
'Solr': '2',
'Analytics': '1'
```

Ops Center is recognizing the analytics node (strangely `dsetool ring` doesn't realize its workload is analytics):

[image: Ops Center Screenshot]

The node's `/etc/default/dse` has `HADOOP_ENABLED=1` and `SPARK_ENABLED=1`

### The problem

Running `dse shark` or `dse spark` on the node just hangs indefinitely. Moreover, system.log is constantly/repeatedly dumping the following:

```
INFO [main] 2014-08-22 22:13:34,580 PluginManager.java (line 223) Activating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ExternalProcessAuthPlugin
INFO [main] 2014-08-22 22:13:34,582 PluginManager.java (line 232) No enough available nodes to start plugin com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ExternalProcessAuthPlugin. Trying once again...
```

I don't have enough context about DSE to understand what's going on. There seem to be a [couple](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201408.mbox/%3CCADfhF1EZWCB4BMP_agmGWjyVJGN-O5rnrda39WbJGrBsvZO5tg@mail.gmail.com%3E) [instances](http://qnalist.com/questions/5068098/spark-on-cassandra) of this problem floating around, but no solutions.

I'd really appreciate some help with this. DSE has been great so far - I would love to get shark working!

Comment: Looks like you are missing the DseDelagateSnitch setup for all of the non Search nodes.  You need to put DseDelegateSnitch in the cassandra.yaml and the real snitch you want to use in the dse.yaml for all the nodes and then do a rolling restart.  Not sure if it will fix this problem, but it will cause you other issues for sure.

Comment: Hi Advait, please try starting the dse node manually by ssh'ing into the box and using: sudo dse cassandra -k. then try dse spark. if that works we can come back and figure out why it's not coming up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** [Just do this](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfSysAuthKeyspRepl.html)

Ended up in the same situation when bringing up a new analytics DC with 2 nodes.

The log message mentioned above is saying that the Cassandra is configured with PasswordAuthentication and so DSE/Spark is looking for a way to create a parallel user to keep it secure.

But when a new DC added, generally the Strategy is changes to NTS for all desired keyspaces - usually the user owned ones. However, the security related stuff is all kept in **dse_security** and **system_auth** - which also need to be using NTS with RF=N. Unless the new DC has these keyspaces, Spark bring up wont happen. The bringup sequence keeps looking for them every 5 secs and prints outs this cryptic INFO message.

**Solution**:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE "system_auth" 
    WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};

ALTER KEYSPACE "dse_security"
    WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2};
```

No restart of the analytics/spark nodes is required. Just run

```
$ nodetool repair system_auth
$ nodetool repair dse_security
```

HTH.

Comment: I just connected the dots on this one, thanks for answering it c360ian!